# How overload the '=' operator with arguments?

Tags: c++, class, templates, operators, overriding

What would be the correct syntax to use the '=' to set some value to a class member and supply additional arguments? E.g. positions in a vector:

```
MyClass<float> mt;
mt(2,4) = 3.5;
```

I've tried:

```
template <class _type> 
_type myClass<_type>::operator()(int r,int c) {
    return data[r*nCols+c]; 
};

template <class _type>  
myClass<_type>::operator= (int r, int c, _type val) { 
    data(r,c) = val; 
};
```

But the compiler tells me I can override the '=' operator with 1 argument.

Comment: `operator =` should assign one `MyClass` to another `MyClass`.  If you want to assign to an element then access the element with your `operator()` like you do with `mt(2,4) = 3.5;`

Comment: @NathanOliver it doesn't work, I get " error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Comment: `operator=` has a very limited set of parameters it can take. Effectively there is one parameter, and it is the object being copied. Recommended reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you overload the `=` operator, you only want to have the right-hand value in the arguments. Since you overloaded the `()` operator, you don't need to handle the `r` and `c` value with the `=` operator.  You can just use `mt(2,4) = 3.5;` and the overloaded `()` operator will handle the `mt(2,4)` portion. Then, you can just set the returned data to your desired value without overloading any `=` operator.

You need to return a reference to the data so you can edit it, however:

```
template <class _type>
_type& myClass<_type>::operator()(int r,int c) {
    return data[r*nCols+c]; 
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the reference bit!